# Electron React - How to fetch local JSON file data before App Component renders?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, fetch-api, electron-react

Hello I'm building a Electron + React + Node app.

I need to import data from my app-config.json file into both my server.js(contains server side logic) and my App.js file.

This is my project structure:

```
electron-react-app
-build
-dist
-public
--app-config.json
--server.js
--index.html
--electron.js
-src
--App.js
--index.js
---components
```

I need the data inside my app-config.json to be imported into my files so I can use said data into my variables.

I can easy do it on my server.js like so:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");
const { SerialPort } = require("serialport");
const axios = require("axios");
const _ = require("underscore");
const fs = require("fs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const shutdown = require("electron-shutdown-command");
const { app } = require("electron");

const newApp = express();
newApp.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(newApp);

const appConfigFile = require("./app-config.json");

let clientPort = appConfigFile.clientPort;
let serverIP = appConfigFile.serverIP;
let serverPort = appConfigFile.serverPort;
```

But on my App.js I try to fetch my data before declaring my const socketio but the class AppConfig variables come as undefined and the io.connect() function is not properly executed.

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

export class AppConfig {
  static serverIP;
  static serverPort;
}

fetch("app-config.json")
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then((data) => {
    AppConfig.serverIP = data.serverIP;
    AppConfig.serverPort = data.serverPort;
  });

export const socketio = io.connect(`http://${AppConfig.serverIP}:${AppConfig.serverPort}`); 
//these variables come as undefined

function App() {...}

export default App;
```

Would there be a way to render my App.js component only after the app-config.json data is fetched?

Ill also add my app-config.json here:

```
{
  "serverIP": "localhost",
  "serverPort": 5000,
  "clientPort": 3000,
}
```

Any help would be greatly aprecciated.

**Edit:**

This is my index.js file, where my App.js is rendered.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-tailwind/react";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <ThemeProvider>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

Comment: Where is the app component rendered? You export it and it has to be used somewhere

Comment: I've eddited my question with my index.js file, where App.js is rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class AppConfig {
  static serverIP;
  static serverPort;
}

fetch("app-config.json")
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then((data) => {
    AppConfig.serverIP = data.serverIP;
    AppConfig.serverPort = data.serverPort;
  })
  .then(() => {
    io.connect(`http://${AppConfig.serverIP}:${AppConfig.serverPort}`);
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
    root.render(
      <ThemeProvider>
        <App />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  });
```

Comment: This seems to almost do the trick.
Now it seems that data is actually being fetched and App.js renders, but now I get  error 'socketio' is not defined at my App.js file.

What do I need to do at App.js file in order to make my const socketio = io.connect(AppConfig.socket); ?

Comment: Finally got it working thanks to yoursuggestion, I didnt realize I havent passed my class data into my App component. Once I did it, just had to move my const socket io inside of App function and it all works, thanks a lot @Konrad